# Blueimp File Upload: single file upload

Tags: html, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using Blueimp [File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), how can I limit the upload to the last single element selected or (drag and) dropped? I already deleted the `multiple` attribute from input form and I set the `maxNumberOfFiles` option to the value `1` but if the first upload fails (because of the option `maxFileSize` or `acceptFileTypes`) the first element stays on top of the listed selected files (generated by template) and further files cannot be uploaded because they infringe the `maxNumberOfFiles` option. I'd desire that if an accepted file is upload and/or dropped, instead of being appended, it would replace the old (not accepted) file. I would also that the templates never prints more than one file when multiple files are dropped but only the first file.

Comment: are you using the UI version or the basis plugin? show us your code!

Comment: I'm using the Basic Plus UI plugin. It is the standard plugin code less multiple property in input tag
    <input type="file" name="files[]">
as stated in the [plugin FAQ] (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? If so, please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

change input tag from:
`<input type="file" name="files[]">` 
to:
`<input type="file" name="file">`

Answer (score 5):

Remove **files** array and remove **multiple** attribute:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
```

to:

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file">
```

Answer (score 3):

Also change the multiple attribute if it is set from

```
<input type="file" multiple="" name="file">
```

to:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```