# Upload only one file using jquery fileupload in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a live project and there is a requirement to upload only one file and then forced to a user to submit the form.

```
%input#primary-file-uploads{type: "file", name: "upload[upload]", class: "file-input"}
```

I removed `multiple:"multiple"` attribute from input tag but it's still uploading multiple files. how can I approach it to complete my task

Comment: Is this input is in a form?

Comment: @NN796 Yes its input field to upload file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:
`%input#primary-file-uploads{type: "file", name: "upload", class: "file-input"}`

I think `upload[upload]` is forcing it to take multiple files. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451482/blueimp-file-upload-single-file-upload)

A [guide](https://gist.github.com/tveimo/6922245b057a7930e2d8) present to upload a single file. And here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nabeeln796/g6mqrbd2/).

By the way, you can use [remotipart gem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart)

Comment: I tried with your code but now it's not uploading a single file and I am restricted to use jquery file upload not want to use any other gem. https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @VarinderSohal it should work. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451482/blueimp-file-upload-single-file-upload

Can you please post your params in logs after you submit the file?

Comment: @VarinderSohal A working JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nabeeln796/g6mqrbd2/

Comment: @VarinderSohal is this fixed your problem?